# Feeding multiple blocks via callbacks

Tags: matlab, simulink

I created a library for a battery. My model contains multiple instances of this battery and each one is supposed to be configured with variables from an XLS file.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to call the same function from the preloaded callback and write local variables to every battery out of that function. If I write into the "base" workspace the values are overwritten every time I call the function.

Can anybody help?

Comment: hey, man, solved? please, insert some piece of code for us to your issue be better analysed :)